# How do I color a single arrow in a plant UML component diagram

Tags: plantuml

From the documentation its clear of how to color all the arrows using a skinparam and I can change the overall color of a component using colors. Its just unclear to me on how to color the arrows only.

e.g. in the below example how could I make the arrow from component1 to component3 have a different colour

**Plant UML Code**

```
@startuml
  [Component1] as 1
  [Component2] as 2
  [Component3] as 3
  1 --> 2
  1 --> 3
@enduml
```

**Resulting Diagram**

[image]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Add the color within brackets inside the arrow you want colored: `1 -[#blue]-> 3`

You can use hex color code as well: **#0000FF** instead of **#blue** for example.

```
@startuml
  [Component1] as 1
  [Component2] as 2
  [Component3] as 3
  1 --> 2
  1 -[#blue]-> 3
@enduml
```

### Result:

[image]

Comment: 1 -> 3, fix it as 1 -[#blue]-> 3, awesome, what about 1 -d-> 3, we can not use 1 -d-[#blue]-> 3, how to deal with that

Comment: Use 1 -[#blue]d-> 3 instead of 1 -d-[#blue]-> 3.